# Where to study advanced sound design? More inside

Tags: design, sound, showreel, uk, studies

I am Sid and I am a Sound Editor/Designer/Recordist from India. I have been working on movies in India for about 3 years and have recently completed some major mainstream cinema films.

I do tracklaying/editing/mixing and have experience in location sound as well. In addition to doing mainstream movies, I keep doing student films/shorts as a way to work on some fresh cinema once in a while.

I have carried out stereo/surround mixes for television and documentaries and have extensively worked in the film pre dubbing stage creating 5.1/7.1/Dolby Atmos dialogue, foley and sound fx pre dubs.

I had applied to 4 places for an MA in sound design for films and television.

This is a permanent link to my current showreel:

[Click here for showreel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1w5rv36t531SHJGcEV1VEVTamM/edit?usp=sharing)

Now I have an offer from the following places:

1. Bournemouth University - MA in sound production for Film and Television
2. University of Westminster - MA in Audio Production
3. University of York - MA in post-production with sound design

I am from India and dont have much idea about the local standing for these universities. Is anyone familiar with these universities? Has anyone studied any art or design course here? Any information would be helpful.

I have a month from now to make up my mind as to where I want to study.

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I can understand your difficulty in making a decision.
However I feel that you are overlooking the fact that you probably won't learn a whole lot, simply because you already have learned in practice.
Most University courses I know focus a lot on technical aspects, that's not exactly what you need. (That is an impressive list of skills, btw.)

Let me ask you a question: what do you expect from a university course? Whether it's design or art, is not a very big distinction to me. Is it to you?
But most importantly:
Where do you want to be? (not literally) In which aspects do you need to develop yourself, to get there?

Cheers!

Comment: i expect 2 things from the course, one to clear my foundations and build and on my existing skills and two to be exposed to an international market and global opportunities.

Comment: to work and showcase work. This is primarily because the industry here in India is just too fast paced to actually be able to do things right the way they are meant to be done. I have a good job but no life at all. I love my job but it just does'nt make sense to me when I am not even given the time to do things right. I wont wanna call that my work because of that.

Comment: This will help me in networking with some new talent and I've always admired the professionalism that hollywood movies have and I hope this course will give me an opportunity to qualify to that level.

Comment: and all this time working i've realized one thing.. we always tend the learn the most where we wont even think about it. In my field, just observing people work can teach you a lot. So I am sure its not that the course would'nt benefit in any way.

Comment: Hi Siddharth, thanks for the response and vocalising your ideas of what you want. I wasn't trying to tell you that wouldn't learn anything :) I just read @sxa and that sounds like it should be very good for you. Good luck on making a decision. BTW it's really a shame that there seems to be no interest in providing good education in India.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, Masters level courses in arts subjects -tend- to focus more on theory/concept than the technical aspects; its generally expected that you know those already, and that what you're doing is of a personal research nature.  I know that Edinburgh's course is fairly 'conceptually' focussed, for example.

The balance of that may vary among these courses, though, and it usually leans more heavily towards the technical side on those courses aimed at people who have a background in something else.

I'd suggest you have a look at the showreel work for each course, that's often useful.